# How to hold impulse signal in continuous time? (Simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a hard time getting an ideal step signal triggered by an impulse. I'm not able to hold the impulse at its peak.

[image]

In the pictures can be seen that I have some logic producing an ideal pulse with `width = stepsize` and `amplitude = 1` (Scope 1) - but I need a step of the same amplitude. I tried a lot of stuff (memory elements, adding constants and so on) and came up with the idea above. I don't understand why it isn't working? Why don't I get `amplitude = 1` for my step (Scope 2)?

Isn't there a better solution?

some facts:

- I just have the basic Simulink
- it's a time-continuous model
- `convert` is just inverting boolean to double to satisfy the switch conditions

Edit: **It is very important that I only get a step for the first pulse, if it ever happens, that there is another pulse, the output should remain 1.** (well that could be easily solved with a saturation block)

Answer (score 4):

I had a little blackout, the solution for my case (impulse amplitude = 1) is pretty easy:

One could use a triggered subsystem with a constant.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Actually not even the constant is necessary:

[image]

**Anyway, the question is not entirely answered, as it is just working for pulses of `amplitude = 1`. The trigger output is always 1!**